# Automatically generate data in One to One relationship

Tags: mysql

i am currently working on a project and there is database schema that hold one to one relationship between two tables as follow.

```
--Create Table called attendence
CREATE TABLE attendence (date date NOT NULL, 
    epfNo varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
    timeIn time, 
    timeOut time, 
    PRIMARY KEY (date, epfNo)) 
 ENGINE = InnoDB 
 CHARACTER SET = utf8;

 --Create Table called setteams (one to one relationship with attendence)
 CREATE TABLE setteams (date date NOT NULL,
    epfNo varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    team varchar(2),
    operation varchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (date, epfNo),
    CONSTRAINT fk_setteams FOREIGN KEY (date, epfNo) REFERENCES attendence(date, epfNo) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
 ENGINE = InnoDB
 CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

when i'm insert data to attendence table, i want to automatically generate date and epfNo values according to one to one relationship in setteam table.

`ON UPDATE CASCADE` is useless in here.

Comment: I'm not clear how that could work. Can you give an example of an insert to attendance.